# How to configure Ember 2.0 for Integration Testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I created a sample ember-cli project using ember 1.13.5.  I create one component and a dummy integration test.  It runs just fine.

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('selected-product', 'Integration | Component | selected product', {
  integration: true
});

test('amount', function(assert) {
    assert.equal(100.00, 100.00);
});
```

I then update my ember version to 2.0.0-beta.3 in my bower.json file, run the tests, and receive an immediate error:

1. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ember.View.extend')
2. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.cache.subject')

There is literally nothing else custom in my projet.  I just generated it.  I realize it's beta software and not quite ready for primetime, but if anyone knows of a simple configuration change, I would appreciate it.  I'm using ember-cli version 1.13.1.

Comment: What version of ember-qunit are you using?  There have been updates recently for ember 2.0 compatibility that may not be packaged with ember-cli just yet.

Comment: I think you need to be on at least 0.4.2

Comment: @Dhaulagiri, you're right!  If you add an answer I'm happy to give you credit, officially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to the latest version of ember-qunit, v.0.4.4 as of today, as ember-2.0.0-beta.3 compatibility was added in [this commit](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/commit/ead35ac2e8fce09ae2ec577cb90b54dcb7fdff8d).  The version of ember-cli you are using does not come with this version of ember-qunit.